# Slider-Effect doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, transition

I'm trying to get a nice slide-effect on my slider (just from left to right). But it won't work with transition and jQuery.

Is there something wrong in my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.weiter').click(function() {
    if ($('.eins').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.eins').removeClass('active');
      $('.zwei').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('.zwei').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.zwei').removeClass('active');
      $('.eins').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
header section.eins {
  background: url("http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sheep-and-lambs-in-field.jpg");
}
header section.zwei {
  background: url("https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/700px-394px/long-sheep-pregnant_1b7dbe4ddad4dd1.jpg?domain=cx.aos.ask.com");
}
header section {
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  float: left;
}
header section.active {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
.weiter {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <i class="weiter"></i>

  <section class="eins active">
    <span>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
 </span> 
  </section>

  <section class="zwei">
    <span>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
 </span> 
  </section>

</header>
```

Comment: `Is there something wrong in my code` - no errors, but nothing to suggest anything should "slide" at all in either javascript nor css

Comment: Where is your `transition` css you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slider animation is missing from your code. I could add a simple slide transition using the position attributes of your element.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f31moo7y/1/

Refer code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.weiter').click(function() {
    if ($('.eins').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.eins').removeClass('active');
      $('.zwei').addClass('active');
    } else if ($('.zwei').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.zwei').removeClass('active');
      $('.eins').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
header section.eins {
  background: url("http://www.petakids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/sheep-and-lambs-in-field.jpg");
}
header section.zwei {
  background: url("https://aos.iacpublishinglabs.com/question/aq/700px-394px/long-sheep-pregnant_1b7dbe4ddad4dd1.jpg?domain=cx.aos.ask.com");
}
header section {
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
  transition: all .3s;
}
header section.active {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
}
.weiter {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <i class="weiter"></i>

  <section class="eins active">
    <span>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
 </span>
  </section>

  <section class="zwei">
    <span>
   <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
 </span>
  </section>

</header>
```